# Clear content of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have an iPhone application that uses a timer and at every time interval it creates some `UILabel` controls and adds them into a `UIScrollView`.

What I want to do is to clear the `UIScrollView` every time interval before it puts the `UILabel` controls into the `UIScrollView`.

How can I clear the contents of the `UIScrollView`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
for (UIView *subview in scrollView.subviews) {
  [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: or in one line: [scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

Comment: This answer is wrong because the scroll indicators are also subviews of the scrollView.

Comment: I know this is old but I am a bit confused. I was experiencing a problem when adding/removing content dynamically to the uiscrollview it was mixing up old with new content and I was looping thru the subviews and removing them all with for   (int i = 0; i < scrollView.subviews.count; i++)   instead of this. Isn't it the same in the end?

Answer (score 15):

You will also remove the scrollbar with the [above solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062848/clear-content-of-uiscrollview/3062906#3062906). To solve this, you may ask whether the subview about to be removed is a UIImageView instance. Obviously, you will need to do more checks if you happen to have your own UIImageViews in the scroll view.

```
for (UIView *subview in scrollView.subviews) {
  if(![subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I typically go with a **one liner** like this: in case you're interested..

```
while(scrollView.subviews.count > 0) [[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Very simple just write this code inside your loop where dynamic structure is creating and changing it's content frequently.

```
[subview removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line

```
[_ui_scroll.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT:

```
 for  subview in self.scrollView.subviews
        {
             subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
```